# Is there any story behind Dysley's bird?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I've always wondered this from Final Fantasy XIII. You know, Dysley's white bird seems to play an important role during the game: it seems to spy the party during their adventures, and, ultimately, immerses in a pool and gives birth to Orphan.

I never understood what was up with such bird: ***did it have any meaning other than serve Dysley***?

And also: ***why did it have to immerse into the pool to create Orphan***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Menrva](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Menrva) is actually part of Dysley/Barthandelus - just an extension of his power.  Barthandelus hopes to sacrifice himself to revive Orphan in a complicated ploy to then kill him.  In order to accomplish this, he needs all of his power, which means that he has to merge with Menrva to finish the task:

> In the end, after its master is defeated and sinks into Orphan's pool, Menrva flies into the pool to fully revive Orphan as it assimilated Barthandelus unto its body.